# How to Convert excel Date into Year, month and date component or NaiveDate?

Tags: excel, rust

I'm using rust and chrono::NaiveDate to read an Excel file with date column type in it.

The date itself is formatted with "dd-mm-yyyy"

I can read the excel file and found out that the reader I use (https://docs.rs/calamine/latest/calamine/) returns float value for the date

[A documentation in Microsoft site states that the date starts from January 1st, 1900](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487)

The float value in it corresponds to this dates:

| date_value (FLOAT) | real value (in dd-mm-yyyy) |
| --- | --- |
| 44198 | 02-01-2021 |
| 44199 | 03-01-2021 |
| 44200 | 04-01-2021 |
| etc... |  |

Basically I need a function or crate that can calculate month, date, and years from the float value I get. I have no clue on how to do this.

Below is my code

```
let data_type = calamine::DataType::deserialize(deserializer);
    match data_type {
        Ok(DataType::Error(_)) => {
            Ok(None)
        }
        Ok(DataType::String(date_str)) => {
            let msg = "Failed to convert Date. Wrong format or empty.";
            let val = NaiveDate::parse_from_str(&date_str, DATE_FORMAT)
                .map_err(|_| Error::custom(msg))?;
            Ok(Some(val))
        }
        Ok(DataType::Float(dt)) => {
            println!("this is float!!!");
            println!("dt: {}", dt); // dt is a float number that count the number of days from January 1st 1900
            let year  = ? // what should I do here ?
            let month = ?
            let day = ?
            let val = NaiveDate::from_ymd_opt(year, month, day)
            Ok(None)
        }
        _ => {
            Ok(None)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you noticed that a 1 day increase in the right hand column adds 1 to the serial number in the left? If you have a starting date, you should be able to work with that.

Comment: I would use the `=DATEVALUE(<date>)` from Excel. That gives you the number of days from the 1/1/1900 till now. So you don't have to mess with the Locale. This can be changed to `SystemTime` in Rust with eg. `fn checked_add(&self, duration: Duration) -> Option<SystemTime>`. I'm sure there is in the `chrono` crate something similar to add the duration to the 1/1/1900 date to get the current date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution regarding my comment would be:

```
use chrono::{Duration, NaiveDate};

fn main() {
    let start = NaiveDate::from_ymd_opt(1900, 1, 1).expect("DATE");
    let date = start.checked_add_signed(Duration::days(44198));  // date_value
    println!("{}", date.unwrap());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c7104e7b89f591ea0167816b4aa44c35)

Comment: this is much practical for me. Thank you

Comment: for excel I used start date 1899,12,30 as excel considered 1900 as leap year when its not, and calamine start date is 1899,12,30 ie I used from_ymd_opt(1899, 12, 30)

Comment: @Nhon Ha This wrong [1900 leap year behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/wrongly-assumes-1900-is-leap-year) remained uncorrected in Excel and will most likely remain so in the future…

Answer (score 3):

`calamine` has a `dates` feature that adds a `DataType.as_date()` method returning an `Option<chrono::NaiveDate>`.
There are also `DataType.as_datetime()` and `DataType.as_time()`.

I don't know why it isn't documented, so use carefully.

At least, the method code could be a starting point for your own implementation.

Comment: This is weird because docs.rs didn't document items under the `dates` feature. Additionally, the implementation in rust says the date starts at the beginning of Dec 30, 1899.

Comment: @drewtato that's not surprising, though I'm not sure it works on all excel files. Excel has a very wonky view of dates, IIRC the excel epoch can be either 1900 (windows) or 1904 (mac, pre-2011), but for the 1900 thing it incorrectly considered that year to be a leap year (which IIRC it inherited from Lotus 1-2-3), so unless you can implement the same broken leap year calculations a common workaround is to set the epoch to Dec 31, 1899, in which case you have the wrong date from then until March 1900 and it's all right thereafter.

Comment: At least until 2100, but XLS only handles dates up to 2078.

Comment: (IIRC excel's "date serial" is 1-indexed, so January 1st is 1, therefore a conversion to 0-indexing + accounting for the incorrect leap year, gives you December 30)

Comment: @drewtato Also, 1st of January 1900 has the value 1, so it's easiest to subtract 1 from the epoch (once), than to subtract it from the float (every time).

Comment: Did you take your timezone into account in the calculations?